# Get specific Sharepoint fields using FieldValuesAsText CSOM C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

When using the `FieldValuesAsText` option, it returns all the data of 120 columns of text. I only need about 4 columns. I did try putting the columns I wanted with the `FieldValuesAsText` option. It did return the 4 fields I wanted, but the `FieldValuesAsText` area still returned 120 columns.

```
var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
var FieldValues = listItem.FieldValuesAsText;
clientContext.Load(FieldValues);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Does anybody know a way to limit the number of columns returned using the `FieldValuesAsText` option?